# write inner join with sub query in spring data JPA query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, inner-join, jpql, spring-data-rest

I have the below sql query running to have distinct data from table order by date which is working fine.

```
select * from content_details c
inner join(select spendpool_id, max(uploaded_date) as latest
from content_details group by spendpool_id) r on c.uploaded_date = latest
and r.spendpool_id = c.spendpool_id
where c.spendpool_id IN (2,3,4,5)
group by c.spendpool_id order by uploaded_date desc;
```

Here is my JPARepository query for the same.

```
@Query("SELECT m1.spendpoolId FROM ContentDetails m1 join ( "
        + "select spendpoolId, MAX(uploadedDate) latest from ContentDetails "
        + "group by spendpoolId) m2 "
        + "on m1.uploadedDate = latest and m2.spendpoolId= m1.spendpoolId "
        + "where m1.spendpoolId IN (:spendpoolIds) "
        + " group by m1.spendpoolId "
        + "order by m1.uploadedDate desc ) ")
List<Spendpool> findSortedSpendpoolIds(@Param("spendpoolIds") List<Long> spendpoolIds);
```

But whenever I use sub query using query annotation, spring data on runtime cannot recognize the syntax and throws below error.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:
>   ( near , column 85 [SELECT m1.spendpoolId FROM
>   com.beroe.insync2.domain.entities.ContentDetails m1 join ( select
>   spendpoolId, MAX(up Date) latest from
>   com.beroe.insync2.domain.entities.ContentDetails group by spendpoolId)
>   m2 on m1.uploadedDate = latest and m dpoolId= m1.spendpoolId where
>   m1.spendpoolId IN (:spendpoolIds)  group by m1.spendpoolId order by
>   m1.uploadedDate desc ) ]

How can I make this work in jpa ?

Comment: Spring is not throwing any error ... your JPA provider (HIbernate) is., so what is character 85 of that query string? and then you can see the error in your JPQL syntax. You cannot join to a subquery!

Comment: "(" select - the quoted character is there in position 85. When ever I give any subquery in query string like ' ( select ' it starts giving error.

Comment: Which part of "you cannot join to a subquery" is confusing? JPQL syntax is defined at http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/jpql.html#JPQL_BNF_Notation

Comment: You're confusing SQL and JPQL, which are two different languages. They look similar, but are different. If you don't set `nativeQuery = true` in the Query annotation, its value is supposed to be a JPQL query. If you set `nativeQuery = true`, then it's supposed to be SQL. And JPQL doesn't support joins to subqueries.

Comment: I understood inner join with sub query is not supported. Can u let me know in JPQL hw can I achive the SQL query. Bit lost here.

Comment: my purpose here is to get the distinct spendpoolId value from ContentDetails order by date. In sql I have to use join with sub query to achive that, which in JPQL is not supported. Is there any other alternative with out join in JPQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use native SQL query instead of jpa based because while converting to jpa object to SQL query, its not understand '(' , here expecting Object

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).